# binding checkboxes to updating data

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind html checkboxes to data that is constantly being updated.

Previously, I have worked with checkboxes in Angular by binding the checkbox to some property like this;

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.isSelected"/>`

However, due to the fact that the data is always being updated, the checkbox values that the user sets are overwritten because the updated data overwrites the isSelected value.

An example of my problem is here;

http://jsfiddle.net/TE9K3/4/

I'm trying to think of other ways to deal with this problem - has anyone previously dealt with is?

Comment: Instead of replacing the object, you can update existing object properties.

Comment: True, seems a bit of a hack though and would require maintenance as the object changed over time. (Obviously my example is contrived, the data is actually coming from a REST end point).

Comment: why can't you update server when user makes changes so new data reflects user interaction?

Comment: You can try structure like `{selected:false,data:{//data is server object}}`. This way do not need to copy properties but find the record and replace it.

Comment: @GrahamB Still, not updating the whole object is the cleanest solution. you can also simple make a child object, which you update, i.e. `{ isSelect: true, actualDataObject: { ... }}`

Comment: so seems like I totally agree with @Chandermani, I am just typing slower :)

Comment: haha :) I like this child object approach you both suggested, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just replace the changed value, not the whole object. This way the selected state does not change by the interval function.

```
function ReasonCtrl($scope, $http) {
   $scope.rows = [{id : 1, isSelected : false, date : new Date().getTime()},{id : 2, isSelected : false,  date : new Date().getTime()}];
    setInterval(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.rows.length; ++i) {
            $scope.rows[i].date = new Date().getTime();
        }
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 200);  

}
```

You can find an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TE9K3/5/